# How to add event listener for html class?

Tags: javascript

If I have HTML like this:

```
<a href="#" class="movieImg"><div class="previewBulk"></div></a>
<a href="#" class="movieImg"><div class="previewBulk"></div></a>
```

and Javascript like this:

```
var movie = document.getElementsByClassName("movieImg");
var preview = document.getElementsByClassName("preview");
```

Is there any way to `addEventListener` to 2 movie a tag and preview `div` tag?
I try for loop but when I do something like:

```
for(var i = 0, j=movie.length; i<j; i++){
 movie[i].style.left = 100;
 preview[i].style.left = 100;
}
```

I get  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined`.

**After change preview to previewBulk, i still get error, my code actually look like this**

```
(function(){
        var movie = document.getElementsByClassName("movieImg"),
        preview = document.getElementsByClassName("previewBulk");
        //result = [];

        for(var i = 0, j=movie.length; i<j; i++){
            movie[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){

                preview[i].style.left = ((movie[i].offsetWidth-preview[i].offsetWidth)/2)+20;
                preview[i].style.top = -(movie[i].offsetHeight+preview[i].offsetHeight);
                preview[i].style.visibility = "visible";
            });

            movie[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
                preview[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            });
        }
    }());
```

Comment: The CSS `left` property (which is accessed through the DOM as per your example) takes a **length** not an integer. Unless the value is 0 **you need a unit**.

Comment: Do u mean sting value? like "100px"?

Comment: You can't include a unit without the value being a string. It doesn't have to use pixels. The rules are the same as for CSS applied directly.

Answer (score 8):

`document.getElementsByClassName` does not return an array. It returns a node list which is traversed like an XML file.

```
    <a href="#" class="movie"><div class="previewBulk"></div></a>
    <a href="#" class="movie"><div class="previewBulk"></div></a>

    <script>

    var movie = document.getElementsByClassName("movie");

    for(var i = 0; i<movie.length; i++){
      movie.item(i).style.width = "100px";
    }​

    </script>
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uy5fk/

Answer (score 7):

```
// for each iterates over a list and runs a function for each element
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach,
    // query selector all runs a CSS selector and returns a list of elements
    // matching the selector
    $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

// for each element in the list returned by the CSS selector    
forEach.call($$('.movieImg, .preview'), function(v) {
  // add an event listener to the click event
  v.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // and run some event handling code.    
  }, false);
});
```

Of course there's browser compliance issues. They need to support ES5 & DOM2 events. Use shims for browser compliance.

If you include

- [ES5-Shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)
- [Flow.js](http://flowjs.com/)

It should fix browser support. Of  course FF4/ Chrome /safari5/ ie9 / Opera10+ already support these

**Edit:**

The problem is actually the ["closures inside loops problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) as described in the [javascript garden](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.closures)

Comment: Must support Es5 and Dom2? because this is my assignment, i not sure my lecture browser support or not. by the way thank

Comment: @bitokeev updated to match your update. It's the closures in for loops that cause your bug

Comment: Thank for helping, but somewhat dont understand the code, too advanced for me.

Answer (score 3):

No tags with classname `preview`  so

```
var preview = document.getElementsByClassName("preview");
```

will cause that error

this line must be as follows

```
var preview = document.getElementsByClassName("previewBulk");
```

and as @raym0nd said the number of `div` tags must be equal to the number of `a` tags

**EDIT**

the problem with your code is you used the index of `for` loop inside the anonymous function but this function is called with `mouseout` and `mouseover` event and after finishing the `for` loop try the following

```
var movie = document.getElementsByClassName("movieImg");

    for(var i = 0, j=movie.length; i<j; i++){
        movie[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
        var preview = this.getElementsByClassName("previewBulk")[0];
                          preview.style.left = ((this.offsetWidth-preview.offsetWidth)/2)+20;
            preview.style.top = -(this.offsetHeight+preview.offsetHeight);
            preview.style.visibility = "visible";
        });

        movie[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
            var preview = this.getElementsByClassName("previewBulk")[0];
            preview.style.visibility = "hidden";
        });
    }
```

or test in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CjWBQ/33/)

Comment: still get error after changing from preview to previewBulk, i edit and post my full code on the question, can u help me look for the problem? Thank

Comment: Thank, it work.  about the code "var preview = this.getElementsByClassName("previewBulk")[0]" may i know what does the [0] mean? is't an array by accessing the first element?

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0, j=movie.length; i<j; i++){
 movie[i].style.left = 100;
 preview[i].style.left = 100;
}
```

does preview has the same length as movie? if not this gives you an error.

Comment: Yes, preview has the same length as movie

Answer (score 1):

You have `class="previewBulk"` and `document.getElementsByClassName("preview");`

Your code assumes there will be as many elements of the class `preview` as there are for `movieImg`, but since you got the class name wrong, there are going to be zero such elements.